# IIS not directing to correct web page as visual studio.

Tags: asp.net, iis, windows-server-2012

When I created my webpage on IIS Windows Server 2012 and click on the links to switch between pages the first link works perfect as expected. When you click on another link that resides in another folder I receive a 404 Error.The Alias is causing my web page to fail. If I add the Alias then it works perfect. But it has to be done manually within the URL.

Heres an example of how the link is displayed. This works perfect as expected.
http://localhost/MyAlias/Folder/webpage.aspx.

When you click on a different link that resides in a different folder in VisualStudio it drops the Alias and causes a 404 Error. http://localhost/Folder2/webpage2.aspx. Why is the Alias being removed if I applied it to my website? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you link your pages? Show some code.

Comment: Its just an asp.net page that's listed under a folder. Example. Folder1 has webpage1. Folder2 contains webpage2. It works perfect in VS but when you add the Alias in IIS it's causing an issue. It's only added to one page but drops when you click to a different link. Is there a way to remove the Alias?

Comment: But how do you create href link for the webpage2? <a href="????"> It's related url absolute url issue I think

Answer (score 1):

It is just related to how you link your second page. You have to link it with '../'

Here an example:

```
<a href="../Folder2/HtmlPage2.html">../Folder2/This is the link for page 2</a>
```

Comment: Thanks I will give that a try.